# Java RenderedImage subsection

Tags: java, image-processing

I am trying to get a subsection of a RenderedImage in java. Say for example the image is 100x100 and I want the bottom right hand corner of that image so

```
RenderedImage i=...
    x=49;
    y=49;
    width=50;
    height=50;

RenderedImage i2=...
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `RenderedImage` is a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html), you can simply use the `getSubImage()` method:

```
BufferedImage bi = ...;
BufferedImage bi2 = bi.getSubImage(x, y, width, height);
```

Note: `bi2` will share the image data array with `bi`.

If your `RenderedImage` is not a `BufferedImage`, you have to do it the "harder" way:

```
WritableRaster raster = i.getData(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height))
            .createCompatibleWritableRaster();
Hashtable<String,Object> properties = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
for (String name : i.getPropertyNames())
    properties.put(name,i.getProperty(name));

// And finally creating a BufferedImage
// which of course implements RenderedImage:
RenderedImage i2 = new BufferedImage(i.getColorModel(), raster,
       i.getColorModel().isAlphaPremultiplied(), properties);
```